# How to check and Uncheck checkbox and also how to make the checkbox click out of the row click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Only one row having class `highlightRowSelected` one time and that row's checkbox is ticked - this is  working

How to make other checkboxes deselect which does not have class `highlightRowSelected` and also other rows checkbox es can be ticked but that should not add class `highlightRowSelected` to that row , only row click(not from checkbox col) should add the class `highlightRowSelected` to that row

**you can change the function declaration and make a pure js call rather than specifying getdetails(row) in the html..
Also the rows are dynamic so cant hardcode id or something in html**

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7jqb5hp/13/

```js
function getdetails(row) {
  el = window.event.srcElement;
  if (el.id.substr(0, 7) == 'eachRow')
    el = null;
  if (row.cells[0].children[0].checked == false && el != null) {
    row.cells[0].children[0].checked = true;
  } else if (row.cells[0].children[0].checked == false && el != null) {
    row.cells[0].children[0].checked = true;
  }

  $("#tableID tbody tr").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("highlightRowSelected");
  });
  
  $(row).addClass("highlightRowSelected");
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.highlightRowSelected {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
    <th>checkbox</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Alfreds </td>
    <td>Maria </td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Centro </td>
    <td>Francisco </td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Ernst </td>
    <td>Roland </td>
    <td>Austria</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be doing what you require already. The checkbox is checked on row clicked, and only the last clicked row is highlighted. If that's not what you want, please give a clearer description of the problem and the behaviour you want

Comment: edited the desription

Comment: You should be using radio buttons instead of checkbox...

Comment: it has to be a chkecbox  -- sorry requirment cant change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed the second condition of your JS code, added to unselect others:

```
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

And took away the call `getdetails` from the header row.

Also added:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

to handle the checkbox ticks separately from row clicks.

```js
function getdetails(row) {
  el = window.event.srcElement;
  if (el.id.substr(0, 7) == 'eachRow')
    el = null;
  if (row.cells[0].children[0].checked == false && el != null) {
    $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    row.cells[0].children[0].checked = true;
  } else if (row.cells[0].children[0].checked == true && el != null) {
    row.cells[0].children[0].checked = false;
  }

  $("#tableID tbody tr").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("highlightRowSelected");
  });
  
  $(row).addClass("highlightRowSelected");
}

$('input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.highlightRowSelected {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
  <tr>
    <th>checkbox</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Alfreds </td>
    <td>Maria </td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Centro </td>
    <td>Francisco </td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Ernst </td>
    <td>Roland </td>
    <td>Austria</td>
</table>
```

Comment: for other rows which does not have class attached needing two clicks to deselect the checkbox

Comment: I added unchecking of others

Comment: unchecking is working , but when clicking other row's  checkboxes its adding the class and and checkbox is not getting ticked  . --- it should be just opposite

Comment: what should happen is when clicking on other rows checkboxes  it should not add the class and it should tick the checkbox

Comment: can you please reverse this

Comment: I'm Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

update your js function:

```
function getdetails(row) {

   if ($(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
     $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
     $(row).removeClass("highlightRowSelected");
     return false;
   }

   var isChecked = false;
   $("#tableID tbody tr").each(function () {
     if ($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
        isChecked = true;
     }
   });

   if (isChecked) {
     $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
     return false;
   } else {
     $('table input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
     $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
   }

   $("#tableID tbody tr").each(function () {
     $(this).removeClass("highlightRowSelected");
   });

   $(row).addClass("highlightRowSelected");
}
```

updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7jqb5hp/15/)

Comment: How to make other checkboxes deselect which does not have class highlightRowSelected    -- this is working nicely but   Other rows checkboxes can be ticked but that should not add class highlightRowSelected to that row or checkboxes tick should not go to the click function

Comment: no little bit different - sorry if i am confusing you  . only the checkbox click on only should tick the checkbox , now its ticking checkbox for other rows when i am clicking on them and not adding class . now if one row is getting class , then other rows are never gonna get the class again .

Comment: what should happen is when clicking on other row's checkboxes only  it should not add the class and it should tick the checkbox

Comment: oh then we need to add click event on checkboxes too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143659/discussion-between-tripathy-and-abdul-rafay).

Comment: can you please add the checkbox click event then . also if you want to remove that getdetails(row) you can add your own jquery click function as rows are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```
use jquery to trigger the function,

ex.

<tr id="1" onclick="checkMe(this.id)"><input type='checkbox'></tr>
<tr id="2" onclick="checkMe(this.id)"><input type='checkbox'></tr>

jquery:

function checkMe(id){
        $(this).closest('[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
}
```